# Lipschitz continuity and differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas for this one? could use some help.

Comment: Write down your favorite non-Lipschitz function and see if you can find two solutions to the corresponding differential equation.

Comment: It should be noted that there exist non-lipschitz choices of $f$ for which the IVP has only one solution.

Comment: @T.Bongers so perhaps an exponential function?

Comment: @terribleatmath Try instead to find a function whose derivative blows up at a point in $\mathbb{R}$, say $0$.

Comment: @T.Bongers $\sqrt{x}$ looks like it may work...

Comment: @T.Bongers yeah, it will work. I just have to figure out how to find a solution to $y'(x) = \sqrt{y(x)}$. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like I can separate variables or anything like that here -- can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess $f(t)=\sqrt t$ works out fine.

So now you want to find a solution $y$ to $y'(x)=\sqrt {y(x)}$. This is a separable equation. If $y'(x)\neq 0$, $$y'(x)=\sqrt {y(x)}\iff y'(x)(y(x))^{-1/2}=1\iff (y(x))^{1/2}=\dfrac x 2+\dfrac C 2,$$
which implies $y(x)=\left(\dfrac x2+\dfrac C 2\right)^2$.

But you want $y(0)=y_0$. Let us choose $y_0=0$ for simplicity. "So $C$ must be zero", not quite because the solution we got was for whenever $y(x)\neq 0$. It could be that $y(0)=0$, so this suggests looking at $$y_1(x)=\dfrac {x^2}4 \text{ and } y_2(x)=\begin{cases} 0, &\text{if }x\leq -C\\\left(\dfrac x2+\dfrac C2\right)^2, &\text{if }x\ge -C \end{cases},$$ where $C$ is a negative number, (you want to shift to the right, so the solution is worth $0$ at $0$, hence picking a  negative $C$). This $y_1$ is only good on $[0, +\infty[$.So make another adjustement:

Take $$\varphi _1(x)=\begin{cases} 0, &\text{if }x\leq 0\\ \dfrac {x^2}4, &\text{if }x\ge 0\end{cases}\text{ and }\varphi_2(x)=\begin{cases} 0, &\text{if }x\leq 1\\\left(\dfrac {x-1}2\right)^2, &\text{if }x\ge 1 \end{cases}$$

You should check that $\varphi _1$ and $\varphi _2$ are differentiable and are solutions to the I.V.P..

Comment: Hm, I was thinking it would work because of the $C^2$ -- like, $if C = 2$ and $C = -2$, we still get $4$ for $C^2$.

Is this a commmon thing: taking a guess like this and needing to adjust it? what should I know to adjust it to?

Comment: Guessing certainly is common in differential equations. See the term [*ansatz*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz). But this an example that isn't specific to differential equations. You're trying to find a counter example for something, this doesn't have to come through a deductive reasoning. An educated guess can take you far, on all areas of mathematics. As for the rest of the comment, I didn't understand it. Do you still need help with this?

Comment: @terribleatmath I had a mistake in my answer, I now fixed it.

Comment: yeah, i'm just wondering, what small adjustment should I make to this f to make it work? how do you figure that out?

Comment: hm, how about $f(t) = \sqrt{t} + \sqrt{t-1}$?

Comment: @terribleatmath Unnecessary complications, set $f(t)=\sqrt{|t|}$ and you're done.

Comment: it's $\frac{x}{2}$ of course.

Comment: @terribleatmath I deleted that comment. Read the one above.

Comment: @terribleatmath Many apologies. I don't know what I was thinking, there is no adjustment to be made. What I gave are solutions to the IVP as you should verify.

Comment: Ah, okay. ill trust you. thanks so much!

Comment: last question before I approve your answer: it should be $f(t) = \sqrt{|t|}$ not just plain old $t$? and the rest of the work is still the same?

Comment: @terribleatmath Do you still need help? May I suggest we delete all these comments since they are now useless?

Comment: no i am fine thanks! why delete them?

Comment: @terribleatmath Because they pertain to a different version of the answer. It's your choice, though.