# Differential equation with $x'(t)=\sqrt[5]{(x(t))}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the following Cauchy problem for $t\in\mathbb R$
>
> $x'(t)=\sqrt[5]{(x(t))}$
>
> $x(0)=0$
>
> Is the solution unique ?

Now this is a differential equation of the form $x'=f(x)$, thus;

$\displaystyle\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)$ we can integrate

$\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{f(x)}dx=\int1dt=t+C$

If I apply it for my case, I obtain $x=(\frac{4}{5}t)^{5/4}$

Can you verify this ?

and $x=0$ satisfies also the condition, why it is not unique, we had only 1 uniqueness theorem, Cauchy-Lipschitz, but that states that if $f$ is Lipschitz, then the solution is unique not the converse, can you help please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose that you mean $$\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{f(x)}=\int dt=t+C$$

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You are very welcome ! By the way, your result is **the** result.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici but why it is not unique ?

Comment: I would say, the diferential equation will have even trivial solution x \equiv 0.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770448/lipschitz-continuity-and-differential-equations/770592#770592) for a way to directly find all solutions and hence deduce non-uniqueness even if you have no idea of whether the solution was unique or not.

Comment: f is not Lipschitz, which follows from the non-uniqueness of the solutions by contrapositive, and can also be verified by looking at difference quotients for f between x=0 and x=a for small a (i.e. f has a vertical tangent at x=0, so those difference quotients are unbounded).